# Hash function for string tree path

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I have a tree that has nodes and connections. One node can have multiple children and the tree is not cyclic. Each node will have only one travel path from the root to the node .

For the unique traversal path in am generating a string called a PATH. It's a string node name plus order ( left to right ). The formula is ( node name - order - current node )

Path ensures the uniqueness. For the given string i want to generate a unique 32 alphanumeric. How to do that, what is a suitable hash function?

Something like

```
function( N1-1-N2-3-N5 ) = 'HNLKJHDSVX6790978767098'   // 32 digit
```

It should output the same hash for the same input. It's not required for security, just for collision detection.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD5, which, cryptographically speaking, is broken, is still viable as a simple hash function, which is why I think it will suit your fancy. Just stick with the hexadecimal notation for the hash function and you should have your 32 byte hash.

[Take a look here](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/hash_generator/hash_generator.php)

> The MD5 (Message Digest) algorithm is a widely used cryptographic hash function producing a 128-bit (16-byte) hash value, typically expressed in text format as a 32 digit hexadecimal number.

Comment: Can you help me with collision detection?

Comment: @Sumeet If collisions can/will be a problem then you should rather use SHA2 than MD5

Comment: @Sumeet All hash functions have collision occurrences, and it took "Equation Group" a decade of cryptography with the best cryptographers known to man to find a collision in MD5; I doubt that you will run into collisions with this setup, but RecursiveExceptionException is right, if you want to drastically lower the probability of a collision use SHA-256, as it is 128 more bits than MD5.